# A regular expression in Perl to capture the Fork bomb command

Tags: regex, perl, bash, shell

I am trying to come up with a regular expression in Perl to capture the following fork bomb command:

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

Below is what I have come up with.

```
:\s*(\s*)\s*{\s*:\s*|\s*:\s*&\s*}\s*;.*:
```

I agree that there are limitations with this regex. The fork bomb command can be easily altered and the given regex won't capture it. However a regex is a requirement. Is there a better way to capture this particular one in Perl?

Comment: What's the point? You alter it a bit, it's still a fork bomb, but the regex won't recognize it..

Comment: Trying to capture this with a regular expression is, ultimately, futile. Do not run shell commands from untrusted sources.

Comment: Are you trying to capture *exactly* the above command or *any* fork bomb command with your regex?

Comment: If you want to catch it for the purposes of stopping it from running, I don't see how that's practical.  The better way to handle this is by editing user/group limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: “*regex is a requirement*” – is this homework? If so, this is more about your understanding of regex metacharacters than about providing security. Have you escaped all characters that need escaping? No – `|`   delimits alternatives, `{}` is a repetition operator, and `()` is a capture group.

Comment: @amon: Thanks. I have escaped the characters you mentioned. Following is my regex: ":\s*\(\s*\)\s*\{\s*:\s*\|\s*:\s*&\s*\}\s*;.*:". Do you have any other comment? Eventually, I would like to create a regex that works even when the function name ":" is changed.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially:

```
/\Q:(){ :|:& };:/
```

Now tell us what you are really trying to accomplish: what kinds of variations from that exact text do you want to match.  If you can describe it in English, you have a shot at getting a regex for it; if not, not.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that \Q returns the value of all the following non-word characters backslashed. However your regex does not capture the fork bomb if there are extra white-spaces in between. Eventually, I would like the create a regex that captures the given fork bomb even when the function name ":" is different.